# Email confirmation with prototype.js?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, prototypejs

I have a simple name and email form built in Ajax, PHP and mySQL.

The user enters a name, and email address and the fields are saved into a database.

How can I once the name and email have been submitted, send a confirmation email to this user?

Comment: With prototype.js? You can't. You need to use something server side.

Comment: Can you give us some more info on this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're after (double) opt-in. Just to give a basic outline how you can achieve your goal.

- Register user details to your db.
- Store a unique token for every user (every action: new user/lost pw/etc.)
- Store a token lifetime value (the date until token is accepted as valid)
- Use some Mail library for PHP ([PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/))
- Send a greeting (validation) message for every new user including their unique tokens
- If user opens the provided link, you could set a flag so user is active from now on.

Note: Since this is just a basic outline i am not mentioned any security pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't provided us much info that's why I'm just giving a imperfect answer here.--

See first in your registration code use `bin2hex` on `username` to generate activation code because this will make sure that each user have different activation code. And use `INSERT INTO` mysql syntax and insert the activation code in a new column named `activation_code` or maybe anything as per your needs.

Secondly if registration is successful just send a mail to the email id you just retrieved from the user using `mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)` function where set `$to` to your user email id.

Then create a page, just name it as `activation.exec.php` where you would get the activation code from the `URL`, the `URL` has to be sent to the user, and don't forget to include `user id` or `email id` in that link.

Thirdly add a mysql query to check that the user id you just got from the `URL` is in your database or not. And then check that the activation code in the database is similar to the one you just received from the `URL`. And if successful redirect him to the Activation Successful page.

I hope this would help you.